# QR decomposition in linear regression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, linear-regression

I have an exercise where I am to use QR decomposition on a linear regression problem. In order for it to work, I understand it that the matrix `A` needs to be a square matrix. In linear regression this is not always the case, and to work around this problem I am tasked to use QR decomposition where `A` is replaced by`B =Transpose(A) * A`. I have been working in R and found [this](https://r-snippets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/la/qr.html) example.

I don't understand how the use of `B` affects the computations of the QR decomposition of `A = QR`.

Regards

Comment: *"I have an exercise where I am to use QR decomposition on a linear regression problem. In order for it to work, I understand it that the matrix A needs to be a square matrix."*  This is a misunderstanding.  All you need is for $A$ to have all columns linearly independent then run "thin QR" factorization.

Comment: I am sure my teacher said it the matrix needed to be a square matrix (constituted by Transpose(A) * A). Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: Look, the only requirement for standard linear regression is to have injective $A$, then run thin QR factorization.  What you are currently saying is wrong-- ask your teacher to re-clarify what the lesson was and what the assignment is.